# How to make Solr suggestion on copyField work?

Tags: solr, search-suggestion

I don't know why my copyField doesn't work. Here is my schema:

```
<field name="name" type="text_name" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>       

<copyfield source="name" dest="nameSuggest"/>
<field name="nameSuggest" type="textNamePhrase" stored="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>

<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textNamePhrase" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>         
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>  
   </analyzer>              
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="text_name" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />        
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.ApostropheFilterFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />        
     <filter class="solr.ApostropheFilterFactory"/>  
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have suggestion setup to do suggestion on the nameSuggest field. If I upload my documents and keep the copyField tags, the suggestion doesn't work (no results return). However, if I remove the  and upload data with both fields: name and nameSuggest (the client duplicate those fields), then it suggestion works.

Can you tell what is wrong with my copyField? How to know if nameSuggest field is populated or not? I cannot see it returns from my query.

Thanks,

Comment: The `<copyfield..` is written completely in the lowercase. Maybe that is the issue? Could you please check if it works with `<copyField` as stated in the [SchemaXml documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `<field>` elements should be inside a `<fields>` element.
2. Put your  `<copyfield>` element AFTER closing the `<fields>` element.

Something like:

```
<fields>
  <field name="name" type="text_name" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>       
  <field name="nameSuggest" type="textNamePhrase" stored="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
</fields/>

<copyfield source="name" dest="nameSuggest"/>
```

To know if an indexed field is populated, you can either use the schema browser in Solr:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/[CORENAME]/schema-browser
```

or query the terms component

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/[CORENAME]/terms?terms.fl=name&terms.regex=.*&terms.regex.flag=case_insensitive&wt=json&omitHeader=true
```

Comment: I tried it and it still didn't work. My client is using binary to upload documents, could that be a problem?